# primeng text editor icon and label is not displaying

Tags: angular6, jhipster, primeng

I don't see the icons of the buttons within the primeng Text Editor that I use in the Angular project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtGZF.png)

I added to the module: `import { EditorModule } from 'primeng/editor';`

in HTML below:

```
<p-editor class="fa fa-xxx"  [(ngModel)]="text1" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>
                <p>Value: {{text1||'empty'}}</p>

                <button pButton type="button" label="Clear" icon="fa-close" (click)="text1=null"></button>

                <hr style="border-top:0px;border-color:#dde3e6">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeng has dependency on primeng icons. If you want to use icon you have to install it explicitly.

```
npm install primeicons --save
```

Now in your styles.css you need to import the icons like below:

```
@import '../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

or you can add icons in your angular.json file like below:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  //...
]
```

All the details given here [PrimeNg get started](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

Comment: I get error when I do "npm install primeicons --save "

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17763
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\programlar\\mergenEbys\\mergenTechEbysUI\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "primeicons" "--save"
npm ERR! node v8.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALIDI'm getting errors like this

I couldn't upload pictures

Comment: check these links to solve your npm issue : [github issue] (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10713)
[stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458734/npm-err-windows-nt-10-0-10586)

Comment: angular.json is not read by JHipster webpack config, so it is not required here.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for this info...but i haven't tried JHipster yet.